# google maps in aspx

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I've tried to integrate the first example of google maps (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#HelloWorld) in my aspx 4.0 project and it doesn't seem to work.

Is aspx creating a problem (doesn't accept google maps) or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you need to set the height and width ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are doing something wrong, using Google maps in ASP.NET works.

Verify that you have a map div, it has a width and height set, and the way you call the JS code.

And if you'll show the code you're using, we may be able to track the problem for you.

Comment: ah ok, just fixed it! i didn't set the height and width .

Answer (score 1):

Could you give a link to the page where you are having a problem?

Otherwise, it may be easier to use a control such as http://googlemap.codeplex.com/ to simplify adding a map to your page.